# Android - Custom EditText for Odometer Entry

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I'm building am app that will allow Odometer entry.  I would like to use the image shown below as the background on an EditText.  Doing that is no problem, however I can not seem to get the digits entered into the text view to line up in the spaces of the image.  I've tried adjusted the text size, font face, etc.

Here is the image I would like to use...

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?  So that when the user entered digits into the EditText, each digit goes into the correct "slot"?

thank you!!!

Comment: Have you looked at using android:letterSpacing? (only applies api 21 and over)

Comment: @IvanWooll - Awesome, I'll check it out!

Comment: @IvanWooll - I ended up using your solution for letterSpacing and am only showing the background image and settting the letterSpacing if the API is >= 21.  If you add as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android:letterSpacing? (only applies api 21 and over)

Comment: this worked great.  I just only called the letterSpacing method if the device was running android api level 21 +

Answer (score 1):

Set up 6 separate EditTexts on top of that image each with dimensions of the square they need to go into. Then set up event handlers so that it appears to be one fluid motion across EditTexts when the user enters data. Not very elegant but it'll work.

Comment: I've thought of that, but I was hoping there was a simpler way to go about it.  If no one can show a better way I will accept as correct.  Thank you!!